# How do i get a reference of a class in a swift file and code that in another swift file? - xcode / swift

Tags: ios, swift, reference

Im new to swift / Xcode and would like to know how to answer this specific question.

The instruction states that i have to " Get a reference to your model in your TableViewController"

So my question is: How do i get a reference to my Model (Model.swift) in my other swift file (TableViewController.swift) ? What do i have to code in my TableViewController to get a reference?

My Model.swift file contains the following code:

```
import UIKit

class Restaurant
{
  var name: String
  var phone: String

  init(name:String, phone:String)
  {
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: classes in swift are passed by reference and structs are passed by objects... i hope it will clear

Comment: Okay, i will note that down. But im still stuck  on my question :( . I am pretty certain that it is simply just a one line code that i have to implement... but cant seem to figure it out....

Comment: When first using, just initialize your model variable in you TableViewController.swift

Comment: to get a reference, you could just say  var restaurant = Restaurant(name:"myRestaurant", phone:"12345")

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of Restaurant, possibly in your TableViewController.  Let us assume, you are displaying an array of restaurants in your table view.

Do this-

1. Define an array inside your table view controller

   ```
   var restaurants = [Restaurant]()
   ```
2. Somewhere in your controller, say in viewDidLoad, create a few restaurant objects and add it the above array

   ```
   //Create few restaurant objects

   restaurants.append(Restaurant(name:"Rest1", phone:"123"))
   restaurants.append(Restaurant(name:"Rest2", phone:"1234"))
   restaurants.append(Restaurant(name:"Rest3", phone:"12345"))
   ```
3. Load the table view with the above objects via the data source delegates.

In swift you don't need to import Model.swift, etc, once defined in a file, it is automatically available to the rest of the app unless you restrict its access using access specifiers.

HTH.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for your comment but that didnt really help me :/ . I initially have to create an app that uses core data. Ive done every step i needed to do on this tutorial sheet, but im still stuck on the part where i need to get a reference  to my model  in my TableViewController.